# Gitlab CI pipeline include template doesn't work (Secret-Detection)

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I am encountering some weirdness with Gitlab CI includes, anyone ever see something like this?

I am trying to use [gitlab's secret detection](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/secret_detection/) through a simple

```yaml
include:
  - template: Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml
```

which references [this here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml)....but it doesn't work at all, no step ever shows, *unless* I **re** -specify this part from `Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml` but in my own repo's `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```yaml
secret_detection:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

But why would that help if its already in the original `Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml` ??

---

Basically, this doesn't work:

```yaml
include:
  - template: Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml
```

But this does work:

```yaml
include:
 - template: Secret-Detection.gitlab-ci.yml

secret_detection:
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

---

I am using Gitlab 13.2.3 EE. I am working on a branch/not master.

Comment: In your first example, you overwrite secret_detection: rules: if, but in your last example, you only overwrite secret_detection: if. Is that intentional or an oversight? This might be important.

Answer (score 1):

You are including a template, then overriding the default behavior of the `secret_detection` job. However, in doing so, you are actually overriding the entire `rules` section of the job.

This:

```yaml
rules:
    - if: $SECRET_DETECTION_DISABLED
      when: never
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

Becomes this:

```yaml
rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

Is it possible that the `SECRET_DETECTION_DISABLED` variable is defined in your job? If so, using the original template will disable secret detection. By overriding the `rules` section of the job, you are basically not checking `SECRET_DETECTION_DISABLED` anymore. You can check the value of the variable by adding an `printenv` statement to a `script` section in your job.

Comment: The syntax of "if: $SECRET_DETECTION_DISABLED" seems to check whether the variable exists, not its value. I had tried setting it explicitly before like you're suggesting and it always failed, even if set to false. Moment I removed it it worked again (with the extra part also included that I mentioned in my original post)

Comment: You're totally right @KROM , I had overlooked that. You should NOT set this variable to anything since the existence of it will cause secret detection to not run. Can you try running 'printenv' in your job just to see if that variable exists?